# Annoying Wireless Authentication Prompt

Tags: 12.10, wireless, security, gnome-classic, authentication

When my internet connection fails and tries to reconnect (Which happens quite frequently on my crappy Uni Wireless) the following prompt pops up every 20-30 seconds:

[image]

I consider this to be a major security flaw. What if I've let someone else use the computer and the internet cuts out? After 20 seconds this dialogue will pop up and they can just tick the box to reveal my password. Not only that, it's *annoying*. The damn thing obviously remembers my password, I would appreciate it not asking me over and over again whether I got it right.

Is there any way to disable this behaviour? Thanks in advance

EDIT: making the wireless profile available to all users does not solve the problem (The prompt keeps appearing) and makes the security situation even more of a joke. Please reopen?

Comment: I do not know how to disable it, but the reason this happens is because Ubuntu thinks that you might have got the password wrong and that you are being disconnected because of that.

Comment: If you're letting them use the computer inside your account, they can find the wireless password inside the network manager anyhow, not to mention seeing all your other files.  I think the password will not be pre-filled in a guest account.  Agree it's annoying though.

Comment: Hey there, please reopen. The "This question already has an answer here:" part is inaccurate. None of the answers linked there work.

Comment: It is not a security flaw, but it is annoying as a popup disease.